# replace('\n', '') doesn't work well in python3

Tags: python, text, replace

Now I fetch texts from a website and try to delete all new lines in the texts.

The text is like below.

```
'''<style>
    p {
    color: red;
    }
</style>'''
```

Just a simple html or css code.
I'm trying like this.

```
text = '''<style>
p {
color: red;
}
</style>'''

print(text.replace("\n", ""))
```

The output is below somehow.

```
</style>ed;
```

What's wrong???

If I try the same code in the other test.py file, it works as I expected.
But once it's in the real code like

```
correct_codes = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': re.compile(r'correctcode\d*')})
for correct_code in correct_codes:
    text = correct_code.text.strip().replace('  ', '')
    print(text.replace("\n", ""))
```

its behavior is going to be crazy as I mentioned above. Of course the value inside the text variable is totally same with

```
text = '''<style>
p {
color: red;
}
</style>'''
```

I'm really confused and have no idea what to fix...

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: As presented, your problem cannot be reproduced. Please include the actual input along with the full code that's causing problems.

Comment: Is the type of text `str` or something else?  Maybe your input has dos line endings '\r\n'?

Comment: White space is ignored in CSS.  Why do you care about this?

Answer (score 4):

Also replace `\r`.
What you see is exactly what you would see if you were printing
`<style>\rp {\rcolor:red;\r}\r</style>`

On my machine (linux) it takes a `text.replace('\n','\r')` to observe the same result. But that is because line breaks are made of just `\n`. On your machine, Windows obviously, line breaks are made of `\r\n`. So removing the `\n` leaves your with the `\r`. Which, alone, means "go back to the beginning of line, but do not change line".

So, it writes `<style>`. Then overwrite `p {` over it, to have `p {yle>`, then overwrite `color: red;` that is big enough to overwrite everything previously printed. Then `}`, so `}olor: red;`, then `</style>`, so `</style>ed;`

When I say "it overwrites", I mean `print`, on the screen. It is just a printing effect (what does the terminal emulator does when it is instructed to print a `\r`). The text variable still contains everything, but the `\n`, of course.

Comment: The explanation is correct, but it's not "obviously" a Windows-only issue.  HTTP specifies CRLF line breaks.  So, regardless of your local system's line convention, if you're handling data that originated from an HTTP connection, you should expect line feeds.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yes, but they are not. It is not data from the web, but data hard coded in a sample code (that may be an attempt to reproduce same problem seen with data from the web, sure. But the reason of my "obviously" is because the OP obviously experimented themselves with small code examples on their machine, and got this problem. And to open an empty file, type `text='''....''''` `print(text)`, and get that problem, well, you have to be working on a windows machine (at least if I assume that the world is split into windows/mac and other unix machines. Which is practically true)

Comment: But indeed, if the remark is: « *`\r\n` may also impact people who are not working on windows, so the knowledge that sometimes, you also need to remove `\r` is also for non-windows users, * », well I agree. It is even the reason why I know about it, when I haven't used a windows machine since Windows 3.11.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine with \n and \r\n

```
print("".join(text.splitlines()))
```

Or you can replace \n and \r\n with regular expression - I think it should be faster

```
import re
print(re.sub("\n|\r\n", "", text))
```